# VBA chart/object border/fill colour change

Tags: vba, excel, colors, excel-2010

Hi I am currently working in Microsoft Excel 2010 and am trying to change the colour (and other properties) of a specific data point on a chart. So far I have tried:

```
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(4).Select
    With Selection
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        .MarkerSize = 10
        .MarkerStyle = 8
    End With
```

The code runs fine and the rest of the macro runs perfectly, (with size changing to 10 and style changing) apart from the colour staying the default blue! I have tried changing the colour index to Black and White - this doesn't seem to fix the issue.

After poking around I also tried:

```
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(4).Select
    With Selection
        .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .MarkerSize = 10
        .MarkerStyle = 8
    End With
```

I also tried:

```
.ForeColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

and

```
.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
```

But I'm unsure how the last one works fully.

I'd really appreciate some help with this and I'd be happy to PM an example copy if someone would be willing to take a look!

(To reiterate - the activechart part of the function works fine - as does the following marker size and style changes)

-- Hash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do this using properties that belong to cells

Try using this instead

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(4)
    .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .MarkerSize = 10
    .MarkerStyle = 8
end with
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I can't believe I spent over 2 hours searching for this exact fix and failed to find it. At least this post is well tagged!

Comment: @Tom and Hash do either of you know how to change the outline of the  points in a bar chart? I can't seem to find the syntax and it's driving me bananas.  I'm using "With ActiveChar.SeriesCollection(1) methodology. Sorry to tag onto this question - let me know if it's against stackoverflow blog rules

Comment: @John - this is off topic. Start a new question with what you've tried and Myself or someone else will take a look at it